# Disable the default in props in production in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Below is my code.

```
props: {
  year: {
    default: 2016,
    type: Number
  }
}
```

I have used the default value to see the mock but now How can I disable the default value when in production?

Comment: Depending on how you set up your environment, you could check `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` and then define your prop accordingly.

Comment: @FlorianHaider thanks but could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you set up your production environment as described in the docs (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Development-vs-Production-Mode), you can then check your `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable when defining your prop:

```
props: {
    year: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {
        type: Number
    } : {
        type: Number,
        default: 2016
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you build for production? Do you use webpack?

Comment: Yes, I'm using webpack and there I have process.env used.

Comment: Ok, can you add your `webpack.config.js` to your question?